# How to access public variable from other class without static keyword

Tags: android

Here is Class A

```
public ClassA {
public ArrayList<AppDetail> apps;}
```

here is class B and I have to access public method "apps" without static keyword in Class B.

```
public class AppsListActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apps_list);

}}
```

Comment: Well from Class B you could do this : ClassA a = new ClassA(); then a.apps..

Comment: How are you populating the `ArrayList` in `ClassA`? Typically you would create a `ClassA` instance, and use a "getter" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are populating the data in `apps`. Ordinarily, you would create an instance of `ClassA` in `ClassB`, and use getter/setter methods to adjust the values:

```
public ClassA {
    private ArrayList<AppDetails> apps;

    public ClassA() {
        apps = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ClassA(ArrayList<AppDetails> apps) {
        if (apps != null) {
            this.apps = apps;
        } else {
            this.apps = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public void setApps(ArrayList<AppDetails> apps) {
        this.apps = apps;
    }

    public ArrayList<AppDetails> getApps() {
        return apps;
    }
```

And then create an instance in `ClassB`:

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
```

And use the getter/setters methods on `classA`.

However, if you are creating a `ClassA` instance in a separate `Activity` in want to retrieve the data from there, this method will not work, as any data stored in the one instance will not be present in the new one created in `ClassB`.

Comment: if you instantiate apps array using setter method  (setApps )then what is significance of calling that in constructors.

Comment: @bpA To guard against `NullPointerException`s, either as a result of calling `getApps()`, or in case Tarikhelian has any other methods in this class he hasn't mentioned that require `apps` to be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

A variable that is not marked `static` are called *instance variables* or *instance fields*. As the name suggests, you need an *instance* of that class to access it. You create an instance of ClassA like this:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
```

And you can then access it like this:

```
a.apps
```

However, it is not recommended to mark variables/fields `public`. You should mark it `private` and write a getter method and a setter method (optional) to access it or set its value:

```
//getter
public ArrayList<AppDetails> getApps () {
    return apps;
}

//setter
public void setApps (ArrayList<AppDetails> apps) {
    this.apps = apps;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If Class A is POJO (Plain Old Java Object) you can instantiate it and provide a getters and setters.

ClassA.java

```
public ClassA {
   public ArrayList<AppDetail> apps;

   public ArrayList<AppDetail> getApps(){
      // other codes....
      return this.apps;
   }

   public void setApps(ArrayList<AppDetail> apps){
      // other codes....
      this.apps = apps;
   }
}
```

From the other class:

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
// some codes....
// classA.getApps(); //  returns the value of apps for classA instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor if you need. And call something like

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
```

and use as:

```
a.apps;
```

Comment: @Tarikhelian, ok, this answer will also work and PPartisan answer is far better. Please mark his answer as solution and upvote the same. :)